# How to get a url parameter in Magento controller?

Tags: magento, url, controller

Is there a Magento function to get the value of "id" from this url:

http://example.com/path/action/id/123

I know I can split the url on "/" to get the value, but I'd prefer a single function.

This doesn't work:

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

It only works if I use http://example.com/path/action?id=123

Comment: $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); this is only work in class that extends to Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action (on admin) or Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action (on frontend). if that didn't work, it means your controller's not called.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Magento's default routing algorithm uses **three part** URLs.

```
http://example.com/front-name/controller-name/action-method
```

So when you call

```
http://example.com/path/action/id/123
```

The word `path` is your front name, `action` is your controller name, and `id` is your action method.  **After** these three methods, you can use `getParam` to grab a key/value pair

```
http://example.com/path/action/id/foo/123

//in a controller
var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParam('foo'));
```

You may also use the `getParams` method to grab an array of parameters

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams()
```

Comment: I see. However I think the problem was also because I hadn't defined a router. I was using a rewrite:

Comment: <config>    
  <global>
    <rewrite>
      <whatever>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/?ajax/product/item#]]></from>
        <to>/mymod/mycon</to>
    </whatever>
  </global>
</config>

Answer (score 7):

If your url is the following structure: `http://yoursiteurl.com/index.php/admin/sales_order_invoice/save/order_id/1795/key/b62f67bcaa908cdf54f0d4260d4fa847/`

then use:

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id'); // output is 1795
```

If you want to get All Url Value or Parameter value than use below code.

```
var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParams());
```

If your url is like this: `http://magentoo.blogspot.com/magentooo/userId=21`

then use this to get the value of url

```
echo $_GET['userId'];
```

If you want more info about this [click here](http://magentoo.blogspot.com/2014/01/get-id-from-url-in-magento.html).

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Magento module, you can use the Varien Object getter. If it's for your own module controller, you may want to use the register method.

Source: http://www.vjtemplates.com/blog/magento/register-and-registry