# URL parsing for magento

Tags: php, magento, url

I have following url http://dev.test.com/index.php/socialcoupon/index/deletecoupon/id/28

I need to extract the last digit 28 and put it inside a variable named $id in php. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You could probably just `explode()` then `array_pop()`. I am not sure if there is a Magento specific function that will grab that value, but that would be better if you could use a prebuilt function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

write this in your `deletecoupon` function.

You will get the value in `$id`

You may also use the `getParams` method to grab an array of parameters

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

For more check this : [How to get a url parameter in Magento controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211647/how-to-get-a-url-parameter-in-magento-controller)

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it in controller action then you can use it like below.

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```