# Change theme based on param url

Tags: magento, events, observers

I would like to know if I can change the theme based on url parameter (or if it's too late) and if it is possible which is the right event to observe
I have only found a guy who was talking about observing `controller_action_predispatch` but with this event I can't still access to the parameters url (based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19214765/1139052)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do that a number of different ways. That answer is not saying the URL params are inaccessible in the `controller_action_predispatch` event, however you might want to do it during an event like `controller_action_layout_load_before` instead [and create custom layout handles from your param value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021402/1737136). You can get them in your observer like this:

```
public function getExampleParam(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $request = $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest();
    $param = $request->getParam('example');
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I can change the theme, the problem is that `$request = $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest();` return this error: `Call to a member function getRequest() on a non-object`

Comment: @Razorphyn - Did you end up using the predispatch or another event?

Comment: I tried your event, I can change the theme if I declare it explicitly, because I can't retrieve the URL param...so now I'm trying with a controller action, but I'm not able to render the product(I have opened another question)

Comment: @Razorphyn - I'd have to see what gets passed to that event, but quick and dirty global call to `Mage::app()->getRequest()` would probably work instead.

Comment: `Mage::app()->getRequest()` works, thank you very much